# Play Live Video On website using Media server

Tags: web, red5, live-streaming

I am working on a project in which visitor/registered user will be allowed to view the live recording of the ip camera installed at the workplace. How can I achieve this? I have googled everything but have not got solution yet.

I have installed red5 media server, how can i push the live video(not recorded) the server and make it visible to the viewers. Or Is there any other easy/better alternative available.??

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

You need red5 Flex for live video stream over any cam or webcam.

https://code.google.com/p/red5-flex-streamer/